# How to export MongoDB data from Google Cloud Compute Engine>Storage>Disk?

Tags: mongodb, image, google-cloud-platform

I had a GKE cluster, with different webapps and a MongoDB database, that was deleted due to some problems with the billing. GKE just dissapeared but I still have the source code in another repo, so no problem to redeploy it.

If I go to "ComputeEngine>Storage>Disk" section, I can see the disk of my MongoDB but I cannot figure out how to export the data, in order to use it to populate a new Mongo database in another cloud. I have tried to create an image, but I'm not sure how to manage the image to extract the Mongo data.

I have not found any guide or tutorial about this, any help please?

Thanks too much

Comment: Create a VM with a boot disk. Then, add an additional disk with your MongoDB data. Browse the data, create a file, export this file to Cloud Storage. Then, enjoy! (think to delete your VM and you disk when the transfer has been validated)

Answer (score 1):

As @guillaume blaquiere mentioned :

1. Create a VM with a boot disk.
2. Add an additional disk with your MongoDB data.
3. Choose the Cloud Storage location to export your data to by clicking Browse.
4. Once you choose a Cloud Storage, choose a filename for the exported data. You can use the default filename, or you can choose your own filename.
5. After choosing a Cloud Storage, and entering a filename for the data, click Select.
6. From the Export image page, click Export. After choosing Export, the Cloud Console displays the Image export history, where you can view the data export process.
7. Go to the Storage page to access your exported data.

Checkout the link on [Exporting an image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image_with_a_single_command) for more information.